# Взаимодействие между двумя фрагментами

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, android-viewpager, fragment-manager

В ViewPager устанавливаю два фрагмента

Адаптер:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        this.fragments.add(fragment);
        this.titles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position)
    {
        return titles.get(position);
    }
}
```

Устанавливаю адаптер в ViewPager

```
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ListWordFragment(), "Список");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new AddWordFragment(), "Добавить слово");

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Так вот, первый фрагмент в нем находиться лист а во втором форма для заполнения где при нажатии на кнопку слово которое введено в edit text должно отобразиться в первом фрагменте т.е. в листе. И как сделать такое взаимодействие между двумя фрагментами ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фрагменты у вас сами по себе не существуют. Они существуют в рамках какой то Активити. Взаимодействие между фрагментами организовывается при помощи данной Активити. При этом во фрагменте реализуется интерфейс который будет использоваться Активити.

Comment: Фрагмент не обязан реализовывать интерфейс, т.к. активити имеет полное знание о природе фрагмента, который на ней находится и может вызывать публичные методы фрагмента без нарушения каких-либо принципов. А вот фрагмент обращаться к активити имеет право только по интерфейсу.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Согласен. В приведенном примере один из фрагментов принимает информацию от пользователя, соответственно должен оповестить об этом Активити и сделать это может при помощи интерфейса